# In android how to check continously in background WiFi is enabled or not

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-wifi

I am developing  an WiFi app for the purpose of SMS forwarding .After turning  on the WiFi button and open the app it will display the Ip address like 10.0.0.3 and port number is 33300 in the corresponding edit boxes.The problem is when the app is open when i switch off the WiFi button it should display empty but still it display the IPAddress .Also again when i switch on the WiFi button it should  display the IPAddress .How to check the  continuously WiFi Address at the background and display it in the textbox

```
public class WifiFragment  extends Fragment {
EditText et_portnumber,et_IpAddress;
int port=33300;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wififragment, container, false);
    et_portnumber = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etPortnumber);
    et_IpAddress= (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ipaddress);
    btn_serverOn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_Ok);
    final String strgetIpdaddress= getIpAddress();
    et_IpAddress.setText(strgetIpdaddress);
    et_portnumber.setText(port);
            }
private String getIpAddress() {
    String ip = "";
    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                .getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces   .nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                    .getInetAddresses();
            while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();
                if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                    ip =  inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
                    }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
        }
    return ip;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a broadcast receiver registered to listen for connectivity state changes. Then in your broadcast receiver you can easily determine the type of network you are connected to. From there, if your condition is met, you can send a broadcast that you will receive in your fragment and there you will display the IP address or whatever you want. 
You can find all the relevant information on this page: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html